# GitLab GitHub repo mirroring when not an owner

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Currently I am working with a friend on a project which is hosted on GitHub. I personally wanted to have CI, so I logged into GitLab using my GitHub credentials and imported all my repos. This repo is actually his, but he added me as a collaborator. So now I want to add `.gitlab-ci.yml` and make my pushes to GitLab also go to GitHub.

I wanted to mirror this GH repo. When I went to GitLab repo setting I saw it's already mirrored (Pull) by HTTPS. But I have an orange box with `Disabled` text on it. When I move my mouse over it, it says something like this: `Disabled mirrors can only be enabled by instance owners [...]`. I tried to mirror this repo by SSH, thinking it would maybe change something, but then I received a red box with Error on it, saying something like I can't fetch repo (I checked my SSH keys and my I know I have an access to GH repo) but I guess that's an another issue.

So my question here is: Is it even possible to configure pushes/pulls to/from GitLab so they actually go to/come from this GitHub repo if I am not an onwer (I have pull and push rights on GH)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to configure this locally:

You clone your GitLab repository and type:

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin https://github.com/<auser>/<arepo>
```

Then a simple `git push` would push your commits both to GitLab and to GitHub.
Without having to fiddle with mirroring option.

Comment: Okay, and what about CI? I mean let's say I have some tests configured on `.gitlab-ci.yml`. If the test fail, I wouldn't like the commit to be pushed. Then would it be stopped only on GitLab and go on GitHub or will it be stopped on both repos?

Comment: @dabljues That configuration is purelely local. If you want a second push to be done only at the CI level, then you can configure your GitLab CI pipeline to do a github push if the test passes.